Make user or obtain administrator rights
I installed AirByte docker version and set user and pass through .env file.
But I do not see all the settings.
It’s as if my user is not administrator
I seem to have followed the whole guide but obviously something is missing... I skipped some steps?
Screenshot
Make user or obtain administrator rights.
